# MVC 3 Database First and Entity Framework 4.1: I cannot see the data in my database

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-database-first

I used Visual Studio 2010, MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.1 (Database First) to create a web application using an existing database. In other words the structure of the database was used to generate the basic code for the models. I created controllers with "Controller with Read/Write actions and views, using EntityFrameword" as scaffolding option. However, I cannot see the data that was already in my database when I access the web application, and if I insert new data, I can see it using the web application, but I cannot see it in my database. I am now wondering where my web application is fetching and storing its data. It is as if a new database with an identical structure had been created elsewhere, but I don't know where.

By the way, I specified "New Data Context..." as Data Context Class when creating my first controller.

Comment: have you seen the connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you should start create Db (or another one scenerio to create new db and drop ex)

```
DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OhMyContext> initDb = 
                             new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OhMyContext>();
```

And after that

```
using (OhMyContext context = new OhMyContext())
{
    initDb.InitializeDatabase(context);
}
```

and now you can use your db. it will create SQL server as defined config.

of course you should use your `DbSet<T>` as collections. but data will be modified (update, delete or insert) after `context.SaveChanges()`.

gl.